# Index out of Range when I know that index exists

Tags: python, string, list, indexoutofrangeexception

Trying to make myself a script for parsing text files with many lines. For the life of me I can't figure out why it keeps giving me `IndexOutofRange`, but if I print the contents of my list it displays correctly, when I remove or comment out the print, or try to do any further processing after appending items to the list, I get the same error.

Source text file has a bunch of lines with each piece of data separated by a comma like this: `abc,123456,abcd,efgh` I'm trying to remove everything from the string except the numbered part and then add that "substring" to a list which is then written to an output file. I'm sure the manner I'm writing it is probably not very efficient so please correct as you see fit.

```
import sys

fname = sys.argv[1]
list = []
output = "output.txt"
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for line in content:
        line = line.split(',')
        list.append(line[1])

with open(output, w) as w:
    w.write(list)
```

Index out of Range hits on the `list.append(line[1])` portion.

Comment: My guess, there is row with only one argument, means [1] is out of range.

Comment: Do you have a trailing newline or in other words: an empty last line?

Comment: Your code assumes every line has at least one comma in it.

Comment: Your index is out of range - Python does not lie.  Test the number of elements using `length(line)` after the `split`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your file contains an empty line at the beginning or end, that doesn't contain a comma or any other kind of text.

Try to detect empty lines and skip over them.

```
import sys

fname = sys.argv[1]
list = []
output = "output.txt"
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for line in content:
        if line:
            line = line.split(',')
            list.append(line[1])

with open(output, w) as w:
    w.write(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the problematic row with the above code, it will print for you the problematic line.

```
import sys

fname = sys.argv[1]
list = []
output = "output.txt"
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for line in content:
        if line:
            line = line.split(',')
            try:
                list.append(line[1])
            except Exception, ex:
                print "problem with line", line

with open(output, w) as w:
    w.write(list)
```